# End of step symbol

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing

This is more of a style question.

We all know to end a proof with the good old QED (I use LaTeX's `$\qed$` $\square$). I have a proof that is kind of long, and I was to put a delimiter to say "This is the end of a major part of the proof".
It's not really something that I think should go in a Lemma or anything: it's just sort of the end a part.

EDIT: I use paragraphs right now, and that is really the most common way, I guess, but I'm kind of curious if anyone has other ways of marking pauses or "end of thought".

It's just a homework problem, and it really isn't long enough to even need to break up, but I was curious if anyone had any symbols/ways of doing this. (If your curious as to the problem, I'm proving a topology is metrizable by first proving that my function is a metric and then showing it is a metric for that topology.)

Answer (score 2):

If a proof consists of proving properties (i), (ii), (iii) of an object say, I have encountered $\square_{(i)}$ and the like. However, I think it is much clearer and less confusing to the reader to simply group the text into paragraphs, each one ending in a clear statement what has been achieved and only mark the very end of proof suitably.

> *Proof.*  Yada yada ... This shows that my object has  property (i).
>
> In order to show that my object has  property (ii), consider ... Hence property (ii) holds indeed.
>
> Finally notice that property (iii) follows  from ... completing the proof. $\square$

Similarly, if one wants to prove an equivalence, it is much mor common to group the proof into two paragragphs and *introduce* these with "$\Rightarrow$: " and "$\Leftarrow$: ", respectively, rather than add qed-like symbols at the ends of the parts.

By the way, in your case I am surprised that you are able to show that a function is a metric *before* you show that it is a metric *for that space*. Don't you define your function on $X\times X$ to begin with?

Comment: $\square_{(i)}$ is interesting, but, I agree, kind of weird. Paragraphs is pretty much the way I do it, and isn't really much of the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I'm showing that it is a metric on the set, not the space. (Then I show that the metric actually gives that specific topology.)